# Scroll the browser to make my webapp fullscreen

Tags: android, webkit

when I open android browser it opens in Google for mobile, and the page scrolls down so the address bar is not visible.. how can this be done to have more screen space with my webapp.

I have a webapp that loads a map, but to have more viewing field I will like to start the browser (via a shortcut) without the address bar or scroll up to hide..

thanks.

Comment: This is an implementation of the browser. Use a browser that lets you full screen pages.

Answer (score 4):

```
<body onload="setTimeout('scrollTo(0,1)',1000);">
```